# Python subprocess.call works when script lies in one directory but not in another

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, batch-file, subprocess

**The problem**

I have a Python script that, at one point, calls a subprocess, waits for its execution and then works with the process' results that are written in a file.

```
# call external algorithm and retrieve its results after completion
process_result = subprocess.call([executable, parameters]);
print(str(process_result));
results = retrieve_results(result_file_name);
```

`executable` contains name and path of the file to call, a *.bat script in a subfolder, and `parameters` is a list of parameters fo pass to this script. The *.bat itself sets a path variable and then calls an executable which then in turn computes and saves the results, given the parameters.

This works fine.

However. When I copy all involved files to a directory on the Desktop (or, well, anywhere else) it falls apart. All files and the complete directory structure are exact copies of the working setup. All paths used within the Python script and the *.bat are relative. I've set Windows to show hidden files, and there are none.

Yet, when I run the copied program it reports a "syntax error" and the `process_result` is 1, instead of 0. Then it raises errors because the file behind `result_file_name` does not exist - it has not been created, the executable has not been (fully) executed.

This setup is supposed to work on another computer. If I can't get it to run in a different folder *on the same machine* I don't have very high hopes for this endeavour. Still, I'm at a complete loss as to why and how this is happening.

**The involved files**

Besides the script itself, there is a folder containing the third-party executable which was created in MATLAB and a folder containing log data in *.csv files.

```
.
├── my_script.py
├── estimation
|   ├── estimation.bat (setups Runtime and calls estimation.exe)
|   ├── estimation.exe (does the processing and produces/overwrites estimates.txt)
|   ├── estimates.txt (contains the results of the third-party processing)
|   ├── v901 (MATLAB stuff)
|   |   ├── ... 
├── test_inputs (files contain log lines that are processed in estimation.exe)
|   ├── 2016_04_01_04_07.csv 
|   ├── 2016_04_01_04_13.csv 
|   ├── ... (etc.)
```

As I do not have MATLAB, the executable comes with its own MATLAB Runtime located in v901 and its subdirectories, and the executable has to be called using the batch script that first setups the Runtime so that the executable can use it. This is what it looks like:

```
@echo off
:: prepare matlab runtime
set PATH=%~dp0\v901\runtime\win64;%PATH%
:: call estimation algorithm
estimation.exe %*
```

**A minimal example**

I reduced the script to only its interaction with the third-party algorithm to create a minimal example. Both folders (estimation and test_inputs) were copied completely to a new location, as well as the Python script, keeping the file tree intact as given above. 
This code works in the original folder, but not any other. However, I cannot provide the original executable, as it is 1) not mine and 2) needs the v901 folder which is nearly 2 GB.

```
import os
import subprocess
import time

# the folder to watch for new input files 
input_directory = "test_inputs";

# the file to run for processing
#executable_file = "third_party_program\\executable.bat";
estimation_executable = "estimation\\estimation.bat";

# debug line for the algorithm
estimation_debug_line = "null";

# parameters for the algorithm
estimation_parameters = "";

# file in which processing results are saved
result_file = "estimates.txt";



# function to print outputs after succesful processing
def print_processing_results (result_directory):

    try:

        processing_results = result_directory +"\\" + result_file;

        # open the executable's "log" file
        with open (processing_results) as results: 

            # print all lines in the log
            for line in results:                   
                print(line.strip());

    except IOError as ioe:
        print(ioe);


# function that calls the third-party algorithm
def call_function (input_file):

    # memorize current working directory (to change back to it later)
    working_directory = os.getcwd();

    # change current working directory to third party algorithm's directory
    # (necessary for the batch script to work in its folder)
    dirs = estimation_executable.split("\\");
    estimation_directory = "\\".join(dirs[0:len(dirs)-1]);
    os.chdir(estimation_directory);

    # build path to the input file
    input_path = "";
    if (os.path.isabs(input_directory)):
        input_path = input_directory + "\\" + input_file;
    else: 
        input_path = working_directory + "\\" + input_directory + "\\" + input_file;

    # build call strings
    executable = dirs[len(dirs)-1]; # name of the executable file to call
    parameters = input_path + "|" + str(estimation_debug_line) + "|" + estimation_parameters; # parameters for the executable

    try:

        print("now calling: " + str([executable, parameters]));

        # call third-party algorithm 
        process_result = subprocess.call([executable, parameters]);
        print("process_result = " + str(process_result));

        # change working directory back to the original
        os.chdir(working_directory);

        # print results of third-party processing
        print_processing_results(estimation_directory);

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
        print(cpe);




# test the whole thing ---- ------- ---- ------- ---- ------- ---- ------- 
try:

    # initialize latest file
    latest_file = "";

    while (True): # the program loop

        print("... looking for new files ...");

        # retrieve newest file in input directory since last update 
        # (files are sorted alphanumerically first)
        filebase = sorted(os.listdir(input_directory));
        latest_new_file = filebase[len(filebase)-1];
        if (latest_new_file > latest_file): 
            latest_file = latest_new_file;
        else:
            latest_new_file = "";

        # if there is a new latest file, process it
        # with the third-party algorithm
        if latest_new_file:
            call_function(latest_new_file);

        # wait before checking for the next new file
        time.sleep(30);

# upon exiting or force-quitting the script
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print("Script has been terminated.");
```

The output in the original folder:

```
... looking for new files ...
now calling: ['estimation.bat', 'C:\\...(original folder)...\\test_inputs\\2016_04_01_04_07.csv|null|']
process_result = 0
results line 1
results line 2
(...)
... looking for new files ...
Script has been terminated.
```

The output in the another folder:

```
... looking for new files ...
now calling: ['estimation.bat', 'C:\\...(new folder)...\\test_inputs\\2016_04_01_04_07.csv|null|']
process_result = 1
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'estimation\\estimates.txt'
... looking for new files ...
Script has been terminated.
```

(Of course, the actual error is not the problem here, it just results from the executable not being executed (process_result = 1), so the file is not created in the first place.)

Comment: Are you sure that __all involved files__ are copied in the other directory? Also note (I hope I got the scenario right) that on _WIN_, `subprocess` calls [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), and when launching _.bat_ files, that should be done via `cmd /c` (I'm not sure that if this isn't already handled by _Python_).

Comment: Why not try to show us a [mcve]? You may even be lucky, and while you prepare the [mcve] you'll note yourself where the problem lies...

Comment: @CristiFati Well, yes, I copied everything I can see, and that the code actually requires. I added an overview of the involved files to the question. The point of using subprocess was that the script has to wait for the third-party algorithm to finish execution. Anyway, it works in its original folder, so that probably isn't the issue.

Comment: @boardrider Thanks for the suggestion. I added an attempt at brevity which shows the same issues: works in the original folder, but not in another.

Comment: Fun fact: When I run the minimal example from the original folder and call the estimation.bat in the copied folder, everyhing works fine. When I run the minimal example from the copied folder and call the estimation.bat in the original folder, the proces result is 1 again. The executable itself does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: The original folder is a MS Visual Studio project. I don't know whether that is important or whether Visual Studio might be adding something to its project folders (there are no hidden files in the folder, though). The example given above has been created outside of Visual studio and added afterwards, yet it shows the same behaviour.

Comment: I added a visual-studio tag because it does seem to have to do with it. The script works if it is located anywhere beneath C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015. If it lies somewhere else the subprocess.call returns 1.

Comment: Isn't there some env var that points to that folder? Can you dump the environment (`set` command), before the step that fails?

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks, I was thinking it must have something to do with the Visual Studio folders being _special_ but I can't seem to find out what it is. I used `print(subprocess.check_output("set", shell=True))` to get the environment as you suggested. What am I looking for? The variable list is the same when running the script inside the Visual Studio folders as outside.

Comment: The only occurrences of "Visual Studio" in the environment are `VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\ ` and `VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\ ` which don't even point to the 2015 version.

Comment: Hmm, those are only meaningful for _Visual Studio_ and only used at build time, not at run time.

Comment: When you do `diff -ENwbur firstDir/ secondDir/`, are the two directories identical as you asserted?

Comment: @boardrider I'm on Windows. COMP says, they are the same. Anyway, I found a solution (though hardly the reason for this problem ... which still bugs me).

Comment: The problem was that apparently `subprocess.call([executable, parameters])` only worked in the Visual Studio 2015 folder or its subfolders. This did not have to do with the executable itself, a simple *.bat file that just echoed a "Hello World" produced the same error. It turned out that the (not recommended) call in the form of `subprocess.call(executable + " \"" + parameters + "\"", shell=True)` works outside of these folders, too. This is far from a satisfying solution, but my current workaround.